# Why does recursive variadic templates not work as expected?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, recursion, variadic-templates

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T f(T&& a, T&& b)
{
    return a + b;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T f(T&& a, T&& b, Args&&... args)
{
    return f(a, f(b, std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2, 3);
}
```

VS 2015 outputs: error C2672: 'f': no matching overloaded function found

Why does it not work as expected?

Comment: Which of the calls to `f` are you having problems with? There are three in the code you show.

Comment: as a hint g++ 4.9.3 gives following error: 
test.cpp:10:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:49: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('int&' and 'int')
     return f(a, f(b, std::forward<Args>(args)...));

Comment: std::forward is defined in <utility> not <type_traits>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't forwarding `a` or `b` when recursively calling `f`, which results in attempting to call the binary overload with `a : int` and `b : int&`. Here's a first step:

```
template<typename T>
T f(T&& a, T&& b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T f(T&& a, T&& b, Args&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(a), f(std::forward<T>(b), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Now the problem is that all arguments passed in must have the same value category and any lvalue argument will cause an error, e.g. `int i = 2; f(1, i, 3);` will fail. To fix this..:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::decay<T>::type
f(T&& a, U&& b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Args>
typename std::decay<T>::type
f(T&& a, U&& b, Args&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(a), f(std::forward<U>(b), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

which can then be simplified to:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
typename std::decay<T>::type
f(T&& a, U&& b) {
    return a + b;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::decay<T>::type
f(T&& a, Args&&... args) {
    return f(std::forward<T>(a), f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Better use auto as return type. decay<T> does not take care about U. Adding int to float (in that order) must return float, not int.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia : The OP wanted all types to be the same, so no care is taken in my answer to support differing types. There are multiple approaches to doing that, but given the question is tagged `c++11`, simply making the return type `auto` is not one of them. :-[